# How to detect when someone cancels AVPLayer?

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

How can I detect when someone cancels AVPlayer?

Here's my code to show the video. How can I detect when someone exits the video screen?

```
// Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
controller.player = player

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(videoDidEnded), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(videoDidCancel), name: NSNotification.Name.kAVPlayerViewControllerDismissingNotification, object: player.currentItem)

// Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
present(controller, animated: true) {
    Amplitude.instance().logEvent("ac_content_video_start", withEventProperties: [
        "Name": self.book.title,
        "Length": 10,
        "No_upvotes": self.book.starCount,
        "Category": self.book.categories as Any
    ])
    player.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible and there is no such event.

What you could do is to associate a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with the view of the `AVPlayerViewController` where you can capture the stop/pause/cancel events of your `AVPlayerViewController`. Then in your selector you can handle the pause/stop/cancel.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific `delegate` or `notification` that I know of, however I could offer this workaround.

**1. Conformance to the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate**

Make the `UIViewController` that presents the **AVPlayerViewController** conform to the transitioning delegate

```
class YourVC: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
```

**2. Add a var to keep track of video status**

```
// Again, in the VC that presents the AVPlayerViewController
var hasMovieFinished = false
```

**3. AVPlayerController SetUp**

Make the view controller presenting the `AVPlayerController` the `transitioningDelegate` of the `AVPlayerController`

```
let controller = AVPlayerViewController()

// Add this
controller.transitioningDelegate = self

controller.player = player
```

**4. Add this to your movie finish notification handler**

This way you know, the movie finished

```
@objc
func videoDidEnded() {
    print("Video finished")
    hasMovieFinished = true
    
    // up to you if you dismiss the controller or not
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

**5. Finally, implement the transition delegate function**

```
// MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
// Gets called when a modal was dismissed
func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController)
-> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
{
    // The dismissal was before the movie ended
    if !hasMovieFinished
    {
        print("Movie was cancelled")
        // DO WHAT YOU WANT, MOVIE WAS CANCELLED
    }
    
    return nil
}
```